# Using Tensorflow 1.13 and Keras 2.2.4 with Anaconda

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, anaconda

I'm using Python with Anaconda. I have installed Tensorflow and Keras by creating a virtual environment:

```
conda create -n keras-gpu python=3.6 numpy scipy keras-gpu
```

I have used Python 3.6 because 3.7 is officially not yet supported by Keras. This installs Tensorflow 2.0.0 which is a problem because I have to change all imports from `from keras.models import Sequential` to `from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential`. Moreover, while this approach works, pyCharm shows me that `Sequential` and `models` are unresolved reference and that `keras` cannot be found. By the way, how can I fix this? I included python.exe in the virtual environment as the interpreter.

That's why I would like to use Tensorflow 1.13.1 and Keras 2.2.4. How can I create a virtual environment using this versions? `keras-gpu` just installs the newest versions.

Or else is there a possibility to continue using `from keras.models import Sequential` with Tensorflow 2?

Comment: I use Keras in python 3.7 every day, it is not true that it does not support it.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro Alright, I will try Python 3.7. Do you have a solution for the problem that PyCharm does not recognize tensorflow.keras etc. (although it works when running the script)?

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro Is it possible to use import keras.models instead of import tensorflow.keras.models in TensorFlow 2? Otherwise I would have to change a lot in my code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Does this not work for you?

```
conda create -n keras-gpu pip python=3.6    
conda activate keras-gpu
pip install tensorflow-gpu==1.13.1 
pip install keras==2.2.4
```